# Android - How to read video stream with Mediaplayer class

Tags: android, video, stream, media-player, buffer

In my current project, we want to preview an external camera in an Android device.

We have connected the camera through USB and we are receiving a video stream on our Android app.

How can I play the stream with the [mediaplayer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) ?

The camera is able to send any video format we want.

Thanks guys !

PS : If you have any other idea to preview a video from an external camera, i would be very happy :)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps someone, we have found a solution :

We couldn't make the video work with through USB, but we send the video stream through WIFI using the [rtsp protocol](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29).

Have fun !